# What is the best SQL query method to export data from related groups?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have an old data table (in MS ACCESS, if you can believe it) that is supposed to be 'related products' from an older ecommerce store.   I'm trying to salvage these related products for my new store.

The dataset with the following fields/data sample:

```
+---------+------------+-----------------+
| GroupID |  ProductId |       Sku       |
+---------+------------+-----------------+
|    1001 |      12473 |   C2S-44682-AMB |
|    1001 |       3628 |    C-43604-1    |
+---------+------------+-----------------+
```

The "groupID" is the association -- productIds in the same group are related to each other. So these two products are related to each other because they both belong in GroupId 1001.  There are some 3500 rows of data total.

What I need is to export these related products into a new table so that I can import into the new store and retain the related relationship.  The new data needs a different formatted structure:

ParentId (the first product), ChildId (the second, related product)
So -- using my example from above:

```
12473, 3628  (the first product should display the second)
3628, 12473  (the second product should display the first
```

I'm not sure how to author the correct SQL query to locate, loop through, and write these new records into a new DB.

I thought perhaps a "For/Each" loop, but in looking for references, I couldn't seem to locate the proper context (lots of PHP examples, but I'm not strong in PHP and really think there has to be a SQL method to do this).  You can run aggregates on "having" clauses on SQL, but again, that didn't seem right to me either.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: What happens if there are more or less than 2 products in one group?

Comment: Great point:  There are never less than 2 products, and there are sometimes more than 2.... so the 'loop' is necessary, I think.   "for each instance of a match on the GroupID, we need to write the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a loop... just a self-join. Notice I added some records to the test data for a more in depth example.

```
declare @oldTable table (GroupID int, ProductId int, Sku varchar(64))
insert into @oldTable 
values
(1001,12473,'C2S-44682-AMB'),
(1001,3628,'C-43604-1'),
(1001,4896,'C-43-558604-1'),
(1099,4458,'C-xxx-1'),
(1099,5217,'C-asbf3-1')

select
    t1.ProductId as parent
    ,t2.ProductId as Child
from 
    @oldTable t1
left join 
    @oldTable t2 on
    t1.GroupID = t2.GroupID
    and t1.ProductId <> t2.ProductId
```

**RETURNS**

```
+--------+-------+
| parent | Child |
+--------+-------+
|  12473 |  3628 |
|  12473 |  4896 |
|   3628 | 12473 |
|   3628 |  4896 |
|   4896 | 12473 |
|   4896 |  3628 |
|   4458 |  5217 |
|   5217 |  4458 |
+--------+-------+
```

Comment: why not use an inner join rather than a left join? The user said there will always be at least 2 records in the group, so you don't run the risk of losing data, but using a left join implies that you think there may not be a match found. ?

Comment: Because after many answers I've learned to not trust that. I'd post an inner join only for an OP to say they were missing rows... then come back and say "oh, there was one record where there weren't at least two products for a group". Your answer is identical to mine, with an inner join which is almost a duplicate.

Comment: That's fair, but this could cut both ways. In the event that there aren't always at least two records in a group, we'd wind up with [ID, null] on rows, which is counter-productive for this use case. I think an inner-join is the safer option to reliably producing expected results for this scenario.

Comment: counterproductive in that you think it's better to drop records when converting them from an old ms access table to a sql server table versus have it populated with a null in the column? Because that is what would happen with an inner join.

Comment: Counter-productive because of the purpose of the table. OP isn't asking to transfer all product data over, they're asking for relational data. The output table should be the relationships between products, not a representation of all the products in the system. that's why the output is just ID, RelatedID

Comment: I disagree, but i understand your argument. While the elementary example int this question fits, I've never met a DBA that was OK with discarding data during a conversion. OP even used the word **salvage**. But, if they truly didn't have any groups with < 2 products, then the left join won't be a problem anyways. While inner join is faster, 3500 rows is laughable for the milliseconds one would gain with an inner join, or even seconds gained since this is a one time operation.

Comment: Gentlemen -- I am grateful for the details you provided.   I can't add my own two cents on this, but I CAN say that scsimon's proposed solution worked _perfectly_ for my needs.    Thank you for your thoughtful (and, I might add, charitable) assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You need a self-join where you match all products to all other products in the group, but exclude the initial product. I believe this will do the trick for you.

Just replace dbo.Product with your actual table name.

```
select
    ProductID           = P.ProductID,
    RelatedProductID    = R.ProductID
    from dbo.Product P
    join dbo.Product R on P.GroupID = R.GroupID and P.ProductID != R.ProductID
```